# Как лучше добавить несколько переменных в список?

Tags: python, html, list, request, append

```
 users_all = [("Гудов", "Александр", "Андреевич", "13", "М", "id1"),
                        ("Петролов", "Петрол", "Петролович", "24", "М", "id2"),
                        ("Семушкина", "Анна", "Максимовна", "13", "Ж", "id3"),
                        ("Михалёва", "Наталья", "Юрьевна", "37", "Ж", "id4"),
                        ("Биссектрисов", "Максим", "Максимович", "17", "М", "id5"),
                        ("Иванова", "Мария", "Геннадьевна", "27", "Ж", "id6")]
```

*это образец, в который нужно добавить переменные*

я делаю *users_all* глобальной и хочу добавить точно также полученные переменные в этот
список: global users_all

```
@app.route('/add_data')
def add_dating():
    fam = request.form["Фамилия"]
    nam = request.form["Имя"]
    otc = request.form["Отчество"]
    age = request.form["Возраст"]
    pol = request.form["Пол"]
    idi = request.form["id"]

@app.route('/add')
def add():
    add_users = users_all.append(fam + nam + otc + age + pol + idi)
```

**так вот, как лучше в списке *add_users* добавить список *users_all* и другие переменные?**

Comment: а чем существующий код не устраивает?

Comment: дело в том, что код зависит от html-файла, и поэтому очень важно сохранить точное такое же написание переменных, то есть со скобками и запятыми

Comment: Это не ответ на вопрос "что не устраивает". С какими скобками и запятыми? Что нужно получить на выходе? Что получается сейчас?

Comment: `поэтому очень важно сохранить точное такое же написание переменных, то есть со скобками и запятыми` - вы хотите users_all как строку представить или что?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: ("Иванова", "Мария", "Геннадьевна", "27", "Ж", "id6")
в таком виде нужно представить переменные  fam, name, otc, age, pol, idi

Comment: Возьмите учебник и почитайте про списки, кортежи и прочие множества. Это не "такой вид". Эти скобки и запятые вообще не относятся к данным, это просто визуальное указание вам, чтобы вы знали, какой тут тип данных.

Answer (score 0):

следуя из примера, нужно просто добавить скобки, чтобы это стало кортежем и расставить запятые

```
@app.route('/add_data')
def add_dating():
    fam = request.form["Фамилия"]
    nam = request.form["Имя"]
    otc = request.form["Отчество"]
    age = request.form["Возраст"]
    pol = request.form["Пол"]
    idi = request.form["id"]

@app.route('/add')
def add():
    add_users = users_all.append((fam, nam, otc, age, pol, idi))
```